# Magento "Unable to list current working directory"

Tags: list, csv, magento, rate

http://www.keciadesign.dk

I am trying to set up table rates in Magento 1.6.2.0. The problem occurs when I try to upload the file with table rates (CSV-file). Then the error "Unable to list current working directory" appears and I can't go any further.

TMP, Media and Var folders have perm.777.

I have read everything there was to find on the Internet on this problem - many seem to have had this problem but I have yet to see a solution.

**Note:** 
Probably not very relevant, but I am on Unoeuro hosting on a shared serverspot.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm unable to reproduce the problem. The error probably happens in `Mage_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate::uploadAndImport()`. I suggest you use xdebug or add debug code to find the exact line that causes the exception, and then update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to your `php.ini` and find `upload_tmp_dir` option (or use `echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')` in your code. Seems like PHP can't list files in this directory where apache uploads files. I'm afraid you can't change permissions of this folder on shared hosting.

Comment: What we can do in this case?

Comment: Do you mean on shared hosting? Nothing.

Answer (score 15):

With some extensions (Wyomind Simple Google Shopping) the error shows up when var/tmp is missing in Magento directory structure.

Comment: Thanks, that save me a little bit of time.

Comment: Def did not expect the generic sounding error message to find me just what I was looking for here but it did.

Answer (score 3):

The most popular reason of this problem - wrong permissions for `media` directory. It should be writeable by web server. More information can be [checked here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html).

Comment: Thank you. I checked that :-) However, you often forget the simplest things -.-

Comment: This shouldn't be 777 but 755 at best, you're better off changing the owner to the one your webservice is runs on

Comment: no it should not be 777! it should have the correct permissions for the php / web user to access.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be reported if you have ran out of disk space.